# Floating Action Button not Disabled - Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have two floatings actions buttons. I want to disabled them programmatically, and it's working for one button. But the other one is always enabled in the UI. When I looked to his state in the log, it saying disabled but it's working.

It's a trivial piece of code, but I don't get it.

**Setting FloatButtonAction to disabled**

```
fab_nfc.isEnabled = false
fab_sync.isEnabled = false
```

The fab_sync is really disabled but the other one not (in the UI)

```
Log.d(TAG, "Fab NFC isEnabled? = ${fab_nfc.isEnabled}")
```

**Log File**

The log file saying that the button is really disabled.

```
Fab NFC isEnabled? = false
```

**Edit - Sample of code for explanations**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_sync"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_synchronization_arrows" />

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_nfc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nfc_near_field_communication" />
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentMainFrameLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparentBackground"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
   private fun disableFloatButtonsAndShowProgressBar() {
        contentMainFrameLayoutId.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        fab_nfc.isEnabled = false //not working
        fab_sync.isEnabled = false //working
        Timber.d("Fab NFC isEnabled? = ${fab_nfc.isEnabled}") //is false
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how it's possible. The FloatingActionButton are on the create method, with clicklistener on them. I just have a super view (FrameLayout to show a spinner) But it's first state is Gone.

Comment: it would be good if you can share that sample code for more understanding.